# Partly mutable API class with a generic variable holder for client use

Tags: java, api, design-patterns, immutability

I am building an API.  One of its functions is to perform some resource analysis (imagine a document, URI, or DB, not important what) and return a `List<Finding>` where `Finding` is a POJO.  I want the `Finding` to be immutable once returned from the API, with all the data returned by the API, however, I would like to have a single `setUserNote(String)` method for client convenience.

The reason for it is so that a client gets a listing of `Finding`s, it can process them while using `setUserNote` to save its own data in the object itself, like a plain note.  I think that would be a neat convenience preferable to the client having to extend `Finding` just to add that one variable or encapsulate it as an instance variable and then `ExtendedFinding.someMethod() { return this.finding.someMethid(); }` for every method in  `Finding`.  Furthermore, it would be messy, to say the least, for the client to construct `ExtendedFinding` out of the `Finding` he gets from the API.  That's why I plan to just simply give them that one field they can use for convenience.

Questions:

1. Is this bad design and why?  I have never done anything like this before nor have I seen API classes come with an arbitrary data holder variable for client convenience.
2. Let's say this is a bad design.  What would be an applicable design pattern to easily propagate Finding to construct ExtendedFinding by the client?  Surely, you could have something like  public `ExtendedFinding(Finding) { /* copy vars one by one */ }` but that is far from elegant

Comment: Sounds like `userNote` should not be in `Finding`.

Comment: but i am still wondering if this could be an anti-pattern (user convenience data bag var where all other class vars are read-only)

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily bad design. It sounds uncommon though. It is important to keep in mind the probable uses of an API when designing it, but I feel this goes a little too far:

- It breaks the single-responsibility principle: the class now does both its job of representing `Findings` *and* of being a container for user specified data.
- It limits the user to `String` notes instead of arbitrary objects. For example they wouldn't be able to use a Map or a custom POJO if they need to. (This could be easily fixed using generics, though.)

A better solution might be defining the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in the `Finding` class. This way these objects could be used as keys to a `Map`, and users would be able to store their notes outside of your API.

Another solution might defining a new class to represent the pair of a `Finding` and user notes. This has a cleaner "feel" than storing notes within the otherwise-immutable `Finding` class, but the added complexity might make it not worth the effort. Which solution is best really depends on the situation; there is no right or wrong answer.

(By the way, the `final` keyword doesn't make a class immutable. It just means you can't define subclasses for it. You can create mutable classes that are final - take for example [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html))

Comment: Sure, `String` is just for the simplicity of example.  It could be an `Object` or some collection

Comment: as for your 1st bullet, the note would certainly be a property of the finding, sortof like an appendix added by the user.  kindof like when you buy a reference manual and it has 10 blank pages at the end for you to enter your own notes

Comment: yeah, i nuked the mutable question

Answer (score 1):

First your third point, `final` in no way makes a class immutable - it signifies that the class cannot be inherited from. So you cannot `extend` a `final` class.

For your main problem, why don't you cast your POJO to an `interface` and return a list of that rather than the underlying POJO. You can then make your actual POJO class package private so that the client cannot cast it back:

```
public static interface Finding {
    //all public getters

    void setUserNote();
}

static final class FindingImpl implements Finding {

    @Override
    public void setUserNote() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
private final Collection<FindingImpl> findingImpls = new ArrayList<>();

public Collection<Finding> getFindings() {
    final Collection<Finding> findings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final FindingImpl fi : findingImpls) {
        findings.add(fi);
    }
    return findings;
}
```

Comment: sorry, was confused about `final`.  I suppose every var in `Finding` would need to be declared as final except for userNote

Comment: I don't see why - if the end user only has access to the getters and not the setters due to the `interface` (the all the variables are `private`) - then there is no reason to make the variables `final`. This is call encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. If you return a Finding to me, that you consider immutable, how does it make a lick of sense for me to be able to inject a note, one time, into that object? The presumption would be that other people might be shown the same findings, no?

The correct answer here is that you should have another class: FindingComment with the commenter's id, the id of the Finding and a timestamp.

Your instinct that extending the class to glom a comment on is surely correct!